# Importing a text file to NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

[The drive contains the text file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx7ohuz8gxVWVGwxZkdXVFdUYzg) I was mailed with a NetBeans project which is a **.txt file**. I tried to convert it to a zip file and import it but it is not working. How can I use it now?

Comment: you cannot import a project from a text file

Comment: Add the project file to the question (possibly anonymized if necessary for you), and tell the actual file name. Otherwise the question is pretty much unanswerable.

Comment: I have added the text file now, so if you could help.

Comment: It's not a zip file, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Just change the file extension to `rar`. If you read any of the contents of the file, it's obvious that it's a rar file.

Answer (score 0):

The file in question is a `rar` file that has had its extension changed to `txt`.

If you look in the file itself, this can be seen in the heading of the contents as `Rar!`, with the rest of the information as directories and compressed information. If the file extension is simply changed back to .rar this problem will be remedied (not zip, as you attempted before). This will result in a working rar file with the following contents:

[image]